# Perl Script LDAP search returns Hash but $mesg->entry returns nothing

Tags: perl, ldap

This is my first question on StackOverFlow so please let me know if I have done something wrong.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::LDAP;
use warnings;
use strict;
my($user,$ldap,$mesg,$info,$entry,$x,$y);
$user = $ARGV[0];
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new ("dirproxy.paychex.com") or die "$@";
$mesg = $ldap->search(filter=>"(uid=$user)", base=>"ou=people,o=paychex inc,c=us");
print $mesg; #hash of entry
$info = "$user,,";
$x=$y=' ';
foreach $entry ($mesg->entry)
{
    print "hello?";
    if(length $entry->get_value("payxlocation")) #if > 0
    {
        $x = $entry->get_value("payxlocation");
        $x =~ s/,//g;
    }

    if(length $entry->get_value("organization")) #if > 0
    {
        $y = $entry->get_value("organization");
        $y =~ s/,//g;
    }

    $info = "$user,$x,$y";
}
print $info;
```

Printing $info prints "user,,".  The problem seems to be in my foreach statement

```
foreach $entry ($mesg->entry)
```

"$mesg->entry" is empty so it skips over the foreach and prints the user with no additional info.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach $entry ($mesg->entry)
```

should be:

```
foreach $entry ($mesg->entries)
```

More information on [Net::LDAP::Search](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.55/lib/Net/LDAP/Search.pod), where you can see the difference between `entry` and `entries`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, that results in the same thing.  i.e. nothing.  I have tried both...

Comment: in that case, revise your search filter

Comment: This script also worked 2 months.  Same script.  And another script is now broken...doesn't really make sense.

Comment: any changes in the LDAP server?